# How Find $3x^3+4y^3=7,4x^4+3y^4=16$

Tags: contest-math

if  postive real number $x,y$ such
$$\begin{cases}
3x^3+4y^3=7\\
4x^4+3y^4=16
\end{cases}$$

Find $x+y=?$

My try: 
$$4x^4-3x^3+3y^4-4y^3=9$$
$$x^3(4x-3)+y^3(3y-4)=9$$

Comment: What is the source of this question?

Comment: This is Mathematical olympiad problem  in china (2006)

Comment: Probable typo:  the title has a $17$, not a $7$.

Comment: According to [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3x%5E3%2B4y%5E3%3D7%2C+4x%5E4%2B3y%5E4%3D16), there are no solutions where both $x$ and $y$ are positive.

Comment: @DanielR But the question was to find $x + y$.

Comment: @LeeYiyuan "if postive real number x,y such..."

Comment: No real solutions for 17 and 16...

Comment: @DanielR Woops! Missed that out.

Comment: We can find $x^3(4x-3)$, $y^3(3y-4)$ individually but I do not see how that leads to $x+y$.

Comment: @nanchangjian x+y has to be a number or can depend from the variable x and y? otherwise is x+y= $\frac{16+3x^3y+4xy^3-x^4+y^4}{7}$ (i can show the passages if it can depend from x & y =))

Comment: to @nanchangjian: are the numbers in the original questions correct? Os is there a typo?